# call data without refresh

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a small thing, any 1 help me, I really appricciate...
I have a drop down menu,I want when I select the value, it will call the related data, which I am access with php+mysql, I dont want to jump to other page and show

Comment: welcome to SO... please visit faq http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

**html**

```
<select id="select1" size="1">
   <option value="1">value 1</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#select1').change(function(){
   var url;
   if (this.value == 1) {
       url = 'sample1.php'
   } else if (this.value == 2) {
       url = 'sample2.php'
   } else {
       url = 'sample3.php'
   }
   var data = {'id': this.value }
   $.ajax({
      method: 'get',
      data: data,
      url: url,
      success: function(result){
         alert(result);
      }
   });
  });
})
```

**php** sample.php

```
<?php 

   if ($_GET['id']) {
      // do some MySql stuff....
      echo 'some result';
   }
?>
```

something like that... ;)

Comment: 1 more thing, wht If I want to call differnt pages, like 

<select id="select1" size="1">
   <option value="1">value 1</option>
   <option value="2">value 2</option>
</select> 
when value 1 select, call sample1.php
and when value 2 select, hide sample1.php and show sample2.php

Comment: please see my edited jQuery.. and if you are happy, please don't forget to accept answer.. ;)

Comment: thank u soo much again, if u have time, I just want to ask u, 
wht is the use of this... " var data = {'id': this.value } "
can u please tell me ............ 
again thank uuuuuuuuuuuuu :)

Comment: `this` represents the `select` in our case... so `this.value` is the value of the `select`... the `value` changes depending on what option was selected... hope I was clear.. I'm really not good on explaining.. ;)

Comment: also, var data = {'id': this.value } relates directly to the parameters that the php /.net 'controller/page' would be expecting.